# How is money and score calculated in Zombieville USA 2?

Tags: zombieville-usa-2

I repeatedly do the same levels over again and sometimes I get around $400 and other times I get $190.

I currently have the Daddy Warbucks perk maxed to 5 stars but it doesn't seem to make that much of a difference.

I'm unsure with how the game scores kills and distance and I would like to know how this is calculated.

Comment: Well as far as I know, Mikamobile told me that the cash dropped from objects and killing zombies are the cash, and cash alone, I'm not sure if travelling and killing alot of zombies gets you any money. I'll ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about cash, but score is easily calculated. Every zombie you kill sets a multiplier, shown at the top left. The more zombies you kill in a short time without getting hit, the higher the multiplier will go. Say, you kill 3 zombies in a short time? Multiplier is 4. (I assume you already know this, but never hurts to be sure.)

At the easiest level (one star), each zombie is worth three points. This goes for the normal, the running, and the spitting zombies (Basically the ones with yellow eyes, excepting the boomer.). For every star you go above that, 2 points are added to a single zombie. So, for example, if I run the 4 star level (Southtown Mall), I'll get 9 points, times the multiplier, for each zombie. So say I kill ten zombies before the multiplier before the multiplier runs down. That's equivalent to killing 55 zombies (1+2+3...+10) when you only killed 10. That means you get 45*9=405 more points. SCORE!

The fat zombies get more points. The hulks (the ones with red eyes) double your points for a single zombie (so for the ex. above, they score 18 times the multiplier), while the boomers (the ones with odors) seem to add five points (on a level with 11 point zombies, they score 16).

For money, I don't have a direct formula, but there is almost no correlation between distance traveled/health/accuracy and money. It is true that the farther you travel, the more containers you'll see and the more money you'll get from them. But it turns out this gets beaten out by killing zombies (and thus score) with the new update. Case in point: I kill 100 zombies on Broadway (the 5 star level), while only traveling about 250 yards. This nets me about twice as much money as if I just ran for my life, smashing all the containers along the way, traveling 700+ yards and only killing ~10 zombies. (That run, I got $2000 vs. $1100.)

And Daddy Warbucks actually does do shit. I say this b/c with Daddy Warbucks (5 star), what was once 1600 is now 2000! You'd be surprised how much 400 extra dollars gets you.

So that's my spiel. Honestly, the best advice I have for you is kill zombies. Trust me on this one. Hope all this helps. ^v^

Comment: About 3 months later, your answer is the best. Thank you for your contribution.

Answer (score 1):

Picking up money earns you money, nothing else. It might be affected by multiplier when picking up the money or something like that, but I'd say it's *only* what you actually pick up.

This can easily be proven by running a harder level, killing lots of zombies from a distance and carefully avoiding money. I tried, killed quite a few zombies, ran 200+ yards and got 0 dollars. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I believe that if you kill more zombies you get more money. I think that all the money you collect on the ground is a big part of the money you get all together. Very simple:
Kill zombies and pick up money.

Answer (score 1):

I just kill every zombie I see and progress slowly, in order to conserve ammunition. The amount of money bags you collect is mainly influences the amount of money you make; your score on the other hand isn't really affected much at all.

The way I earn money is to survive and just keep collecting money, because death will cause you to lose about 30% (as a rough estimate) of your money. This is based on my experience; I slaughtered my way through William's mall, and earned 3000-4000 all the time, but upon death from over cockiness, it plummets from 3000-4000 to 1000-2000.

Answer (score 0):

Well, pretty simple really. Money is your answer. The more money you collect from blowing up objects and zombies the more money you get. I got about $700 on level 4 just blowing up objects though the whole game.

Comment: I know that more kills, objects destroyed, and distance traveled give you more money. What I want to know is how much a zombie kill would be, how much a bag of money counts for, and how much 1 foot traveled gives.

For example (merely speculation: not factual):
1 Zombie = $3
1 Object = $1
1 Foot Traveled = $0.10

And I have no idea what the skill bonus would add to your cash total.

Answer (score 0):

You only get money through objects. That's it. You get skill bonuses on your money by killing people and accuracy and health, but other than that it's just money you pick up.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually I make about 1.3k to 1.6k every game and what I have calculated is that it's all about the score multiplier and the amount of money you get.

I ran a lot and killed some zombies and the most I've got was 200$ (I also have daddy warbucks 5 starred)

Answer (score -1):

A good way to get a lot of money is by running as far as you can and kill the least amount  of zombies. I heard killing zombies makes your score go down. Do the highest zombie level you have and get as far as you can on it. I got only 3 kills and traveled 500 and I got around 500 dollars. Also while you are running you want to stay in the upper part of the screen, because there are like garbage cans and stuff up there and its the fastest way. Trust me it works.